# Selecting text from unprotected text pdf issue

Tags: pdf, language, encoding, copy-paste, format

I am trying to copy some text from tables in an unprotected pdf. However, when I highlight the text (about size 10 font), it appears as though I am highlighting text with a huge font (size 50+). It is illustrated in the picture below!

[image: Highlighting the text]

I know this is a text pdf as part of the document was selectable as normal. Also when actually pasting whatever I select, the result is garbage text. e.g. for the example above, the pasted result was:

[image: pasted text]

Could this be an encoding issue/language pack problem? How would I diagnose and remedy this?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Use the pdf editors ability to save the document as a word document.  The pdf clearly isn't only text based on the contents of notepad in your screenshot

Comment: I can save it as a .txt doc and not a word doc. I opened the result in Notepad ++ and it was a mixture between legible text and mostly nonsense ACK characters

Comment: Which indicates its not simply text.  My guess the table was an image and/or the document was OCR'ed at some point.

Comment: So the best way to manage this document is to OCR it again myself?

Comment: The confusing thing for me is that, if there were images in the document, when I highlight them and copy to clipboard, surely they would paste into Word and display as images, instead of nonsense text?

Comment: It depends. I have source files that were typed documents 20 years ago, then scanned in the last decade, which even after being OCR'ed had some text that could not be seletected.